# Cookie lost on Google Signin on CORS in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, google-api, cors, google-signin

My AngularJS SPA is hosted on `web.example.com`.
APIs are hosted on `api.example.com`. All requests are made to `api.example.com`

I am using [Cartalyst Sentinel](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel) for Authentication and Authorization. On top of Cartalyst's Authentication, I have also implemented jwt authorization.

My basic login with `email` and `password` is working perfectly.

Next, I try to integration Google Signin. Here are the steps :

1. Make call to Google requesting permissions.
2. Response from Google has `code`, `clientId` and other things that I then pass on to `api.example.com/api/login` through a POST request.
3. This POST request works perfectly, and I get `loggedIn` response from my server. I also get two `Set-Cookie` headers for two cookies from my `api.example.com/login` response.
4. On this response, angular app changes `url` from `/login` to `/home`
5. Inside the controller of `/home` I make a GET `/user/{{userId}}` request to fetch some more data
6. This is where my server responds with 401 as one of the Request headers `Cookies:cartalyst=null` is `null` whereas the second cookie is being sent. (Note that the cookie that is being sent is still not correct and I don't understand where this cookie is coming from)
7. No where is my Angular app have I ever set or fetched any cookie.

Is this an issue with client side routing? Why is the second Cookie not automatically included in subsequent requests? Is this a `CORS` issue?

Summarizing the problem:

`Set-Cookie` from previous request on `login` API response does **NOT** set the `Cookie` header in subsequent requests when I try to login with Google. However, if I login with email/password, everything works well.